# Java Regular Expression Matcher doesn't find all possible matches

Tags: java, regex

I was looking at a code at TutorialsPoint and something has been bothering me since then... take a look at this code :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
      String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      while(m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
      }
   }
}
```

this code successfully prints :

```
Found value: This was placed for QT300 
Found value: 0
Found value: ! OK?
```

but according to the regex `"(.*)(\\d+)(.*)"`, why doesn't it return other possible outcomes such as :

```
Found value: This was placed for QT30 
Found value: 00
Found value: ! OK?
```

or

```
Found value: This was placed for QT 
Found value: 3000
Found value: ! OK?
```

and if this code isn't suited to do so, then how can I write one that can find all possible matches ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of `*` and there comes the [backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

String :

```
This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
```

Regex:

```
(.*)(\\d+)(.*)
```

We all know that `.*` is greedy and matches all characters as much as possible. So the first `.*` matches all the characters upto the last character that is `?` and then it backtracks in-order to provide a match. The next pattern in our regex is `\d+`, so it backtracks upto a digit. Once it finds a digit, `\d+` matches that digit because the condition is satisfied here (*`\d+` matches one or more digits*). Now the first `(.*)` captures `This order was placed for QT300` and the following `(\\d+)` captures the digit `0` located just before to the `!` symbol.

Now the next pattern `(.*)` captures all the remaining characters that is `!<space>OK?`.  `m.group(1)` refers to the characters which are present inside the group index 1 and `m.group(2)` refers to the index 2, like that it goes on.

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/bO5rL5/2).

To get your desired output.

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
  String pattern = "(.*)(\\d{2})(.*)";

  // Create a Pattern object
  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  while(m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3));
  }
```

Output:

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT30
Found value: 00
Found value: ! OK?
```

`(.*)(\\d{2})`, backtracks upto two digits in-order to provide a match.

Change your pattern to this,

```
String pattern = "(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)";
```

To get the output like,

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT
Found value: 3000
Found value: ! OK?
```

`?` after the `*`  forces the `*` to do a non-greedy match.

Use extra captuing groups to get the outputs from a single program.

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
String pattern = "((.*?)(\\d{2}))(?:(\\d{2})(.*))";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      while(m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(4));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(5));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(3) + m.group(4));
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(5));
     }
```

Output:

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT30
Found value: 00
Found value: ! OK?
Found value: This order was placed for QT
Found value: 3000
Found value: ! OK?
```

Comment: thanks... but this returns only 1 match... what if I wanted it to return all of the matches ?

Comment: Ok... this is getting good ! I did what you told me, and I got your answer... BUT my question still remains on why only 1 match is found ? using your code it gives only (This order was placed for QT/3000/ ! OK) and then the loop finishes... how can I get other answers like (This order was placed for QT3/000/ !OK) or (This order was placed for QT300/0/! OK?) or (This order was placed for QT30/00/! OK?) all at the same time ?
Right now the loop only runs once and then it finishes... I want all the possible matches (just like I mentioned above).

Comment: yep, there is  only one match found because all the characters are matched by the above pattern . There isn't any further character to match. You will got two matches if the input has a two lines like the above.

Comment: @Cypher use extra capturing groups to get the above results in a single program. Regex won't loop through each digits or characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
(.*?)(\\d+)(.*)
```

Make your `*` greedy quantifier non greedy by putting `*?`.

Because your first group `(.*)` is greedy it will capture evrything and will leave just one `0` for `\d` to capture.If you make it non greedy it will give you expected results.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/53

Comment: thanks... but this returns only 1 match... what if I wanted it to return all of the matches ?

Comment: @Cypher you can access all by grabbing `m.group(1)``m.group(2)` and so on.See demo.

Comment: @Cypher what do you mean by all the matches?

Comment: just like in the question... isn't something like [This was placed for QT30 / 00 / ! OK?] another acceptable answer ? (or am I wrong ?)

Comment: @Cypher try `(.*?\d{2})(\d+)(.*)`