# What is the regex pattern for extracting data from log4j log?

Tags: java, regex, log4j

I have a log file that contrains entries like following:

```
[08/30/19 16:00:01:001 EDT] [SRNotes_Worker-1] INFO com.emc.clm.srnotes.schedule.SRNotesItemProcessor Started processing the SrTriageFile instance with ID 38 and file ID 250339290
[08/30/19 16:00:01:001 EDT] [SRNotes_Worker-1] TRACE org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 2, parameter value [73651266], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
```

What would be the regex pattern that I can use for extracting all the relevant  fields as following

```
Timestamp: [08/30/19 16:00:01:001 EDT]
Thread: [SRNotes_Worker-1]
Level: INFO
Class: com.emc.clm.srnotes.schedule.SRNotesItemProcessor
Message: Started processing the SrTriageFile instance with ID 38 and file ID 250339290
```

I have written a function that goes through each character of the string and checks for '[', spaces and other rules like such. Based on that I split the log entries. But I know that it's not an elegant solution. I should use regex but I do not have enough idea about it.

Comment: What you are looking for is capturing group

Comment: [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm) guide on Tutorialspoint shows you how to set up a capturing group and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038364/java-regular-expression-matcher-doesnt-find-all-possible-matches) thread on SE talks about that tutorial and about changing it to do something else.

Comment: This should help you get started `^(?<Timestamp>\[.+?\])\s*(?<Thread>\[.+?\])`

Comment: If you can configure log4j, might be worth investigating if you cannot just change the log format to JSON which is more easily processed.

Comment: https://regexr.com/4ns9o

Comment: Not a duplicate of a **_Reference_** !!

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get into how regex works so can build your own expressions, but here is an example:

```
(\[[^\]]+\])\s(\[[^\]]+\])\s([^\s]+)\s([^\n]+)

//Finds a sequence starting with an [ and ending with the next ]
//(between anything is allowerd; n > 0 times any symbol that is not a ])
//The brackets ( ) are symboling a group, which shuold be selected
(\[[^\]]+\])

//Symbols one space
            \s

//Same as the first
              (\[[^\]]+\])

//space again
                          \s

//selects anyhting untill the next sapce
                            ([^\s]+)

//space one last time
                                    /s

//selects anyhting to the linebreak
                                      ([^\n]+)
```

You probably want to tweak this further for your case, but this should be enaugh to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines always look as indicated, you can also use the `String.split` method here.
Split your lines at every space but not if the space occurs inside square brackets. Limit the split length to 5:

```
String line = "[08/30/19 16:00:01:001 EDT] [SRNotes_Worker-1] INFO com.emc.clm.srnotes.schedule.SRNotesItemProcessor Started processing the SrTriageFile instance with ID 38 and file ID 250339290";

//line.split("\\s")  split a string at each space
//line.split("\\s",5) split a string at each space limit length of result to 5
//line.split("\\s(?![^\\[]*[\\]])") split a string at each space but not inside []
```

All the above combined you could do just something like:

```
Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s(?![^\\[]*[\\]])",5)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or save them into an array

```
String[] myData = line.split("\\s(?![^\\[]*[\\]])",5);
```

and access each element, `myData[0]` is your `Timestamp` `myData[1]` is your `Thread` ...